# Destroy nested fields in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, destroy

Good day,

I'm trying to create simple form with list of links in RoR 4 which can be edited and removed.

I've allowed "destroy" at the main post model file
controller->posts.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many(:links, :dependent => :destroy)

accepts_nested_attributes_for :links,    :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:link].blank? },   :allow_destroy => true
```

and I'm accepting the parameters for destroy at the create and update controller

```
    def create
    @new_post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :body, :tag_list,     links_attributes:[:link, :_destroy]))

    if @new_post.save
        redirect_to posts_path, :notice =>"Saved!"
    else
        render new
    end
end

def update
    @post_to_update = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post_to_update.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body, :tag_list,    links_attributes:[:link, :_destroy]))
        redirect_to posts_path, :notice =>"Updated!"
    else
        render edit
    end
end
```

I'm using jQuery to remove the link field and set its destroy value as "true"

```
<h1> Edit post </h1>
<%= form_for @post_to_edit do |f|%>
    Title <%= f.text_field :title %> </br>
    Body <%= f.text_area :body %> </br>
    <%= f.fields_for :links do |b| %>
    <li class = "enter_link">
        <%= b.text_field :link %>
        <%= b.hidden_field :_destroy %>
        <%= link_to_function "Remove", "remove_fields(this)" %></br>
    </li>
    <% end %>
    Tags <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
    <%= f.submit "Update that bitch!" %>
<% end %>
```

Javascript

```
function remove_fields(link) {
    $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("true");
    $(link).closest(".enter_link").hide();
```

}

And here's the problem:
suppose I've got a list of 3 links

```
"link 1"
"link 2"
"link 3"
```

And I wish to edit that list by removing link number 2 and 3.
once I press update the destroy parameters is passed on to the controller, but it wont delete the original lines.

Now I'll get the following list

```
"link 1"
"link 2"
"link 3"
**"link 1" (again, after removing link number 2 and 3)**
```

As always,
your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let me make your life easier and recommend this gem called Cocoon (https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

It creates simple nested forms.

Simply paste this code into your Post form view.

```
  f.fields_for :links do |link|
  render 'link_fields', :f => link
  link_to_add_association 'add link', f, :tasks
```

With cocoon a partial is needed for the nested form, so create a file called _link_fields.html.erb

and inside make sure you place everything inside a div. Their documentation isnt clear on this, but from experience I do know its required.

```
<div class="nested-fields">
f.label :link
f.text_field :link
link_to_remove_association "remove link", f
</div>
```

And thats it!

Comment: This Gem is quite helpful, thanx! it helped me to define the remove/add links in no time. but unfortunately, the main problem described in the original question is yet unsolved. that is, even after removing fields it will only prevent that link from being submitted again but it won't remove it completely.

Comment: @shultz I don't get what you mean? after you remove a link and submit the form the link should be removed from the array.

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
def update
    @post_to_update = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post_to_update.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body, :tag_list,    links_attributes:[:link, :_destroy]))
        redirect_to posts_path, :notice =>"Updated!"
    else
        render edit
    end
end
```

to this:

```
def update
    @post_to_update = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post_to_update.update(
                         params[:post].permit(:title, :body, :tag_list, 
                         ## add `:id` to this one   
                         links_attributes:[:id, :link, :_destroy])
                         ##
                         )
        redirect_to posts_path, :notice =>"Updated!"
    else
        render edit
    end
end
```

you have to permit the `id` in your `links_attributes` params, so that the records don't get duplicated and for `_destroy` to work